# IMAP Extension not working Linux Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, suitecrm

We have SuiteCRM on Azure Linux web app service, and inbound mail is not working
Error

> Inbound Email cannot function without the IMAP c-client libraries
>   enabled/compiled with the PHP module. Please contact your
>   administrator to resolve this issue.

When I am trying to enable **imap.so** or **php_imap.so** extension via *custom* **php.ini** it is not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Just to confirm: Are you referring the similar steps as described in this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-php-configure#how-to-enable-extensions-in-the-default-php-runtime to enable the PHP extension? Are you getting any error message? Have you tried to run phpinfo(); to check whether the extension is been enabled or not?

Comment: You can't setup an IMAP server on App Service if that's what you're trying to do. The only ports wide-open to the public are 80/TCP and 443/TCP. Look at AKS if you really need that, or switch to SendGrid for e-mail handling (you can talk to SendGrid over REST APIs, there's a PHP SDK as well).